# Mapping a function on two nested objects

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to map a function `dplyr::mutate` on two sets of nested tibbles contained in a data set. My goal is to add new columns to each tibble nested in `db$data.y` by using the corresponding coefficients in the nested tibbles `db$data.x`.

Below, I provided a reproducible example. Each row of `db` refers to a different scale that we are validating. The nested tibbles in `db$data.x` contain the variance components that will be used to perform further calculations. The nested tibbles in `db$data.y` contain the same set of two columns wherein the combination of the number of occasions (from 1 to 10) and raters (from 1 to 2) is different for every row.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

coefficients <- data.frame(Scale = rep(1:5, each = 5), 
                           Component = rep(c("R", "S", "T", "RxS", "SxT"), 5), 
                           Value = rep(c(2, 4, 7, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 3, 5, 2, 6, 3, 6, 4, 7, 3, 7, 12, 8, 7, 11, 14, 9, 2))) %>% 
                           group_by(Scale) %>% nest()

sim.data <- data.frame(Scale = rep(1:5, each = 20), 
                       Occasion = rep(1:10, 2), 
                       Rater = rep(1:2, each = 10)) %>% 
                       group_by(Scale) %>% nest()

db <- left_join(coefficients, sim.data, by = "Scale")

#> db
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  Scale data.x           data.y           
#  <int> <list>           <list>           
#1     1 <tibble [5 x 2]> <tibble [20 x 2]>
#2     2 <tibble [5 x 2]> <tibble [20 x 2]>
#3     3 <tibble [5 x 2]> <tibble [20 x 2]>
#4     4 <tibble [5 x 2]> <tibble [20 x 2]>
#5     5 <tibble [5 x 2]> <tibble [20 x 2]>

#> db$data.x[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  Component Value
#  <fct>     <dbl>
#1 R             2
#2 S             4
#3 T             7
#4 RxS           3
#5 SxT           5

#> db$data.y[[1]]
# A tibble: 20 x 2
#   Occasion Rater
#      <int> <int>
# 1        1     1
# 2        2     1
# 3        3     1
# 4        4     1
# 5        5     1
# 6        6     1
# 7        7     1
# 8        8     1
# 9        9     1
#10       10     1
#11        1     2
#...
```

The final goal is to calculate the column `db$data.y$Abs` for each scale for which we need to use the variance components contained in `db$data.x`. I could do this for each scale separately, but it seems extremely time-consuming. Is there anyone who can help with this?

```
db$data.y[[1]] %>% 
     mutate(Abs = db$data.x[[1]][[1,2]] / db$data.y[[1]]$Occasion + 
                  db$data.x[[1]][[2,2]] / db$data.y[[1]]$Rater + 
                  db$data.x[[1]][[3,2]] / (db$data.y[[1]]$Occasion * db$data.y[[1]]$Rater))

# A tibble: 20 x 3
#   Occasion Rater Abs
#      <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1        1     1 13   
# 2        2     1  8.5 
# 3        3     1  7   
# 4        4     1  6.25
# 5        5     1  5.8 
# 6        6     1  5.5 
# 7        7     1  5.29
# 8        8     1  5.12
# 9        9     1  5   
#10       10     1  4.9
```

I have tried with `purrr::map2` but, if I am not mistaken, it works on two columns of the same nested object, whereas in this case, I am dealing with two different nested objects. I would be happy to consider other solutions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right that you can use `map2()`, but you'll need to use it within a `mutate()` so you can use the two nested columns as the first two arguments of that function.

You then can use your current `mutate()` code as the function within `map2()` to modify `data.y`.  You'll see I replace the current `data.y` with the modified object with the same name in the outer `mutate()`.

Something like that would look like:

```
db %>%
    mutate(data.y = map2(data.x, 
                         data.y, 
                         ~mutate(.y, Abs = .x[[1, 2]]/.y$Occasion +
                                     .x[[2, 2]]/.y$Rater +
                                     .x[[3, 2]]/(.y$Occasion*.y$Rater))))
```

The first data frame looks like

```
db %>%
    mutate(data.y = map2(data.x, 
                         data.y, 
                         ~mutate(.y, Abs = .x[[1, 2]]/.y$Occasion +
                                     .x[[2, 2]]/.y$Rater +
                                     .x[[3, 2]]/(.y$Occasion*.y$Rater)))) %>%
    pull(data.y) %>%
    pluck(1)

# A tibble: 20 x 3
   Occasion Rater   Abs
      <int> <int> <dbl>
 1        1     1 13   
 2        2     1  8.5 
 3        3     1  7   
 4        4     1  6.25
 5        5     1  5.8 
 6        6     1  5.5 
 7        7     1  5.29
 8        8     1  5.12
 9        9     1  5   
10       10     1  4.9 
...
```